# Unique constraint violation on similar characters

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mariadb, special-characters, collation

I have a problem with primary keys in MariaDB (I expect it to be the same for MySQL). I'm building a Django app, where some important tables are created by Django with the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  term     VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  enabled  TINYINT(1)  NOT NULL,
  added    DATE        NOT NULL,
  verified DATE        NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

If I insert two rows in this table where `term` is `ó` for the first one, and `o` for the other, I get the error `[23000][1062] Duplicate entry 'o' for key 'PRIMARY'`. Same behaviour occurs for other similar letters, like for example `e` and `é`.
I really find this behaviour weird, as there is no problems with SQLite.

So now the question is: How do I make the database engine see them as different values?

Bonus question: Can I expect the same behaviour from PostgreSQL?

I **have** tried this in SQL, and not just Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as it happens, I answered this question myself while writing it. I realized that I had not tried the combination of the character set `utf8mb4` and the collation `utf8mb4_bin`, and I remembered that the `_bin` collations compare characters at the binary level, without any rules that makes similar characters seem alike. So creating my database with

```
CREATE DATABASE [database_name] CHARACTER SET = 'utf8mb4' COLLATE = 'utf8mb4_bin';
```

did the trick. Alternatively I could have created each table with

```
CREATE TABLE [table_name] CHARACTER SET = 'utf8mb4' COLLATE = 'utf8mb4_bin';
```

, but setting it on the database is the only viable option here, since Django takes care of table creation.

**Update:**

Regarding the bonus question, the short answer is: No.

For details, see [nick-barnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104979/nick-barnes) comment below.

**Update 2:**

Microsoft SQL server (tested on SQL Server 2017 CU3) uses collation to compare strings for equality, so a binary collation, like for instance `Latin1_General_BIN`, need to be used to address this issue on this server.

Comment: Postgres always uses a binary comparison when testing strings for equality, so there will never be any confusion as to whether `o` is equal to `ó` (in a primary key column, or anywhere else). There has historically been inconsistency in sort ordering, as collation was delegated to the host OS, but this was dealt with in Postgres 10 with the inclusion of [ICU support](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/icu-support-postgresql-10/).

Comment: Answer has been updated, and I have verified the behaviour with a test. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: MySQL:  Changing the settings for the `DATABASE` or `TABLE` only change defaults for newly added tables or columns, respectively.  You need to `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ...`